# How to upload multiple images pixel data into one texture in DX12

Tags: directx, directx-12

I have multiple images in forms of pixel arrays. I want to paste them into one big texture and then render the whole texture. For example, I have a car pixel data and a jet pixel data. I want to copy the pixel data of jet at the top of the big texture and copy the pixel data of the car at the bottom of the big texture. 
My idea is creating a big buffer and copy these pixel data manually. Manually means calculate the offset of the beginning pixel of each row and copy rows in a loop. Then submit the combined pixel data to GPU. However, I think the method is inefficient as CPU is doing the loop. So I am wonderring is there any other way can improve this. For example, any D3D function already enable me to do the similar thing and effcient. On the other hand, what the most formal/correct way to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

How have you been uploading your texture data so far? Probably [UpdateSubresources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/updatesubresources1) from d3dx12.h. Did you try to implement something similar to this function? You can peek in the source - it does roughly the following:

1. Map intermediate resource (D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD resource created by you),
2. A sequence of `memcpy()` to copy pixel data to mapped intermediate resource
3. Unmap
4. GPU copy from intermediate to final resource (D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT  resource created by you).

You should do something similar and add required offset calculations to step 2, so the subimages are properly laid out. There isn't any more "formal/correct" way to do this, sometimes you have to do some CPU work.